# Can I obtain a Steam copy of Construction Simulator 2015 if I own it on the Mac App Store?

Tags: steam, legal, mac-app-store, construction-simulator-2015

I own Construction Simulator 2015, which I bought on the Mac App Store. I would like to get a Steam copy so I can play on my (new, more powerful) Windows 10 PC, but I don't want to purchase the game again if I can avoid it.

Can I obtain the game through Steam for free, because I already own it? Through a receipt code or a product Key etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't find any mention of the Mac App Store version in the [CS2015 FAQ](https://www.construction-simulator.com/en/faq#3cs2015), which only states this about playing on Macs:

> **Apple-PCs:**
>
> If you do not yet have a Steam account, you can set one up for free.
>   You will need to download a Steam client to set up an account.
>
> The Steam client is available free of charge at the following website:
>
> Download Steam Client
>
> Please follow the Steam setup prompts and be sure to set up a Steam
>   account.
>
> In order to activate your game in Steam, please do the following:
>
> 1. Open Steam and log into your account.
> 2. Click on the heading “Games” and then the subheading “Activate a Product in Steam…”
>      Follow the steps to activate the product and enter your product key at the end.
>
> Afterwards, Construction Simulator 2015 will automatically be
>   downloaded and installed

I was able to confirm the game exists on the Mac App Store, so this seems to be an oversight in their FAQ. Realising this, I contacted the developer via the [official Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=378204808920211) and relayed your question. This was their response:

> Thanks a lot for getting touch. It is unfortunately not possible to transfer the accounts between platforms.

In other words, unless you have a product key you can activate through Steam, you will have to repurchase the game on Steam if you wish to play on Windows.